# Global randomization in systemverilog across tests

Tags: system-verilog

I have following class.

```
Class A;  
randc int B;  
endclass
```

In my test case I call randomization of this class only once.
Will it make sure that value that I get across tests are unique?

Randc will work only within a testcase mostly.
Do we have any other constraint to achieve this?

Comment: Restructuring it into a single test will lead to long run time. If i am running them in parallel i can use parallel machines for simulation.

Answer (score 0):

What you want isn't possible. This is the main problem with constrained random generation, that across test runs you get a lot of redundancy (randomize the same thing multiple times). This is the trade-off you do to have a faster development time for your tests.